# responsive or fullsize on mobile

Tags: jquery

I have a responsive [WordPress site](http://kunkka.oni.cc), my client wants an option on a mobile to view the site in fullsize, an opt-out responsive option. Now with the help of a fellow programmer here, I got this:

```
<script>
var yetVisited = localStorage['visited'];
if (!yetVisited) {
  // open popup
  localStorage['visited'] = "yes";
  if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    var answer = confirm('Would you like to switch to the mobile version of Klofficerent');
    if (answer) {
      console.log('yes');     
    } else {
      console.log('cancel');
      viewport = document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]");
      viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0');                
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

It sort of works, whenever I visit the link [kunkka.oni.cc](http://kunkka.oni.cc), my site turns to responsive on mobile, but it won't save this setting when I click on other pages and I need it to be. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a parameter to the url with `#` (i.e. `#mobile`), and then check for it with regex when any page loads. You could add it to any anchor `href` attributes on the page when a button is clicked on the page.

This code adds "#mobile" to the page's URL when the button is clicked. When the page loads, if the URL ends with "#mobile", then the code will add "#mobile" to the `href` attribute of all `<a>` tags.

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("#mobile", window.location.href.length - "#mobile".length) !== -1) {
    $("a").each(function(){
        $(this)[0].href = $(this)[0].href.replace(/\#mobile$/, '') + "#mobile";
    });
}
$("#mobile").click(function(){
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\#mobile$/, '') + "#mobile";
    location.reload();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/qLf395dq/3/

Comment: you can explain for me :(